# Проблема с запуском [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src']

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\work\Desktop\AnsweringMachineTelegram-main\src\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

**Код**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from termcolor import cprint
import asyncio

from src.config import Config
from src.service import DataBase
db = DataBase(Config.db_name)


#initialize user agent
client = TelegramClient(Config.session_location, Config.api_id, Config.api_hash)

#Main function
async def main():

    print('➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖')
    cprint(' Пользовательский бот', "cyan")
    print('➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖')

    from handlers import client

    try:

        print('➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖')
        cprint("✅ Успех - Бот пользователя установил соединение с сервером телеграмм", "green")
        print('➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖')
        await client.start()
        await client.run_until_disconnected()
    finally:
        cprint("❌Стоп- пользовательский бот прекратил общение с сервером", "red")


#Starter
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cprint("❌Остановлено - Бот был остановлен пользователем", "red")
```

Почитал информацию и попробовал запуск с других директорий, но не помогло, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

программа пытается импортировать класс Config из модуля с именем src.config, но не может найти модуль src.

Есть несколько возможных причин этой ошибки:

Модуль src находится не в том же каталоге, что и main.py. В этом случае вам нужно будет настроить оператор импорта, чтобы он указывал на правильное расположение модуля src.

Модуль src не находится в вашем пути к Python. Путь Python — это список каталогов, в которых Python ищет, когда вы используете оператор импорта. Если модуль src отсутствует в вашем пути Python, вам нужно будет добавить каталог, содержащий модуль src, в ваш путь Python.

В операторе импорта опечатка. Убедитесь, что имя модуля написано правильно и используется правильный регистр.

Чтобы устранить эту проблему, вы можете попробовать следующее:

Проверьте файловую структуру вашего проекта, чтобы убедиться, что модуль src находится в правильном месте.

Распечатайте значение sys.path, чтобы увидеть каталоги, которые находятся в вашем пути Python. Убедитесь, что каталог, содержащий модуль src, включен в этот список.

Проверьте оператор импорта на наличие опечаток или других ошибок. Убедитесь, что имя модуля написано правильно и используется правильный регистр.

Comment: Возможно, у автора `src` - это вообще не модуль, а просто каталог.

Comment: Каталог с файлом __ init __.py и есть модуль

Comment: Да я знаю, а где написано, что у автора вопроса есть `__init__.py` в этом каталоге? Я что-то не вижу.